# Issue with Multi-select scripting google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following code to enable multi-select entry in two columns AK and AN in my google sheet.

```
 function onEdit(e) {
    var oldValue;
    var newValue;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

    if (activeCell.getColumn() == 37 || 40 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Project Tracker") {
        newValue = e.value;
        oldValue = e.oldValue;

        if (!e.value) {
            activeCell.setValue("");
        } else {

            if (!e.oldValue) {
                activeCell.setValue(newValue);
            } else {
                activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the script seems to be executed upon edit of any cell in my worksheet "Project Tracker" and not only the two columns (AK and AN) I configured in my script.  Any help would be gladly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Add the `Google-Apps-Script` to your tag to add more visibility to your question.

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could consider modifying to the following:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() === "Project Tracker") {

    if (e.range.getColumn() == 37 || e.range.getColumn() == 40){

     // Do something...

    } 
  }
}
```

you could also combine the If statements as you initially did:

```
if(e.source.getSheetName() == "Project Tracker" &&
   e.range.getColumn() == 37 ||
   e.range.getColumn() == 40){
   // Do something...
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response.  I am quite new to google scripting.  Could you show me how I include this with my existing code?  I have tried (several times) without success!

Comment: You only have to change the first `if` to match @Nabnub's last code.

Comment: Many thanks Jescanellas, I tried this but now my columns are not enabling multi-select